# Why does my program have variable lifetime issues when using generators?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, crash, generator, lifetime

If you are not familiar with generators, some background is provided at the end of the question.

I have written a simple generator using VS2015 Update 2 and its `<experimental/generator>` header, with one version taking iterators and another taking ranges and delegating to the iterator version. However, my program does not properly generate what I want, and sometimes crashes.

Here is a sample that crashes:

```
#include <experimental/generator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace stdx = std::experimental;

template<typename It>
stdx::generator<char> lazy(It first, It last) {
    while (first != last) {
        co_yield *first++;
    }
}

stdx::generator<char> lazy(const std::string &str) {
    return lazy(str.begin(), str.end());
}

int main() {
    for (auto c : lazy("abc")) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Visual Studio produces the following debug error:

> string iterator not incrementable

However, if I extract a variable for the string, it works fine, printing `abc`:

```
int main() {
    std::string abc = "abc";
    for (auto c : lazy(abc)) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

If I instead change the range version to take the string by value instead of by reference, it still crashes with the same debug error:

```
stdx::generator<char> lazy(std::string str)
…
for (auto c : lazy("abc")) {
```

What's going on? How do I write my generators to avoid this issue?

## Quick Generators Explanation

Background for those who don't know what generators are:

Generators allow you to write a function that returns a sequence of values, but to write it such that it returns one value to the caller, gives the caller a chance to use the value, and then continues from where it left off when the caller wants the next value.

This makes it possible to write an infinite loop that yields one value at a time and not have it run forever. If the caller requests ten values from the generator, the generator function will partially execute ten times and then stop.

Because values are generated on demand (lazily), one can think of the return value as instructions on how to get the values rather than the entire container of values. This makes it possible to compose the results into an efficient pipeline.

C++ has several proposals that include generators. Microsoft has implemented their proposal in Visual Studio 2015 for projects that use the `/await` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string expires before the iterators do.

The lifetime of the temporary string is not extended by the range for.  This is the same problem as chaining range adapters.

To deal with this, I make my range adapters either strongly range based, or make it iterator based with an optional resource storer.

```
struct nothing_t{};

template<typename It, class Storage=nothing_t>
stdx::generator<char> lazy(It first, It last, Storage s={}) {
  while (first != last) {
    co_yield *first++;
  }
}
```

Now your range based one looks like:

```
stdx::generator<char> lazy(std::string str) {
  auto store=std::make_unique<std::string>(std::move(str));
  auto b=store->begin(),e=store->end();
  return lazy(b,e,std::move(store));
}
```

But really ranged-based is the way to go.

```
template<class It, class Storage=nothing_t>
struct range_t{
  It begin() const{return b;};
  It end() const{return e;};
  It b,e;
  Storage s;
};

template<class It>
struct range_t<It,nothing_t>{
  It begin() const{return b;};
  It end() const{return e;};
  It b,e;
  range_t(It s, It f, nothing_t={}):
    b(s),e(f)
  {}
};
template<class It,class Storage=nothing_t>
range_t<It,std::decay_t<Storage>> range(It b, It e,Storage&& s={}){
  return {b,e,std::forward<Storage>(s)};
}
template<class T, sts::size_t N>
range_t<T*,std::array<T,N>> range(T* b, T* e, T(&arr)[N]){
  // todo
}
```

Now lazy for iterators creates a range and forwards to one-arg version.

Basically range is a better fundamental unit than iterator is.

Of course, by the time you have `range_t`, much of the shine wears off generator, other than for type erasure purposes.

```
template<class R>
auto lazy(R r)->stdx::generator<std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(r))>>
{
  for(auto&& x:r)
    co_yield decltype(x)(x);
}
template<class It>
auto lazy(It b, It e){
  return lazy(range(b,e));
}
```

Which is short and sweet, and minimizes layers of type erasure.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the first example, recall that the range-based for loop is equivalent to:

```
{
    auto && __range = lazy("abc"); 
    for (auto __begin = __range.begin(), __end = __range.end(); __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        auto c = *__begin; 
        std::cout << c; 
    } 
}
```

## Parameter By Const Reference

Now consider the lifetime of the temporary string to which `const std::string &str` in `lazy` refers. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe that the rules allow for the temporary to live as long as the function parameter in the first place. Changing the body of the range `lazy` to iterate over `str` and `co_yield` the values does not work, which hints at this lack of lifetime extension. However, even if it could live as long as the parameter, this still wouldn't work.

Consider what actually happens here:

1. `lazy("abc")` is called. It calls `lazy(str.begin(), str.end())` for its return value.
2. Because the iterator `lazy` uses `co_yield`, its body doesn't start executing until its returned generator is iterated over.
3. The call to the range `lazy` finishes. The parameter `str` is destroyed.
4. The declaration of `__range` finishes, with its value being a generator that will return to the iterator `lazy` to generate values. The temporary string is destroyed.
5. Iteration occurs and the iterator `lazy` uses iterators for a destroyed object.

By declaring `abc` above the loop, the string being iterated over is alive for the duration of the iteration. Thus, the example works with this change.

## Parameter By Value

Next, let's take a look at the example taking `str` by value:

1. `lazy("abc")` is called. A `std::string` is created and `lazy` receives its own copy of that string.
2. Range `lazy` calls iterator `lazy` and returns the generator. As before, iterator `lazy`'s body doesn't start executing yet.
3. The call to range `lazy` finishes. The parameter `str` is destroyed.
4. The declaration of `__range` finishes.
5. Iteration occurs and the iterator `lazy` uses iterators for the destroyed `str` parameter.

As you can see, taking the parameter by value does not influence the result.

## Solutions

### No Iterators

The first solution is to move on from iterators. With proper range utilities, one can easily take a range and turn it into a smaller range.

```
stdx::generator<char> lazy(std::string str) {
    for (char c : str) {
        co_yield c;
    }
}
```

If a caller wishes to use a substring, they can use any number of utilities. Perhaps there's a generator function `substr` that lazily produces the substring. More generally, a `take` function will lazily produce the first N values and a `skip` function will lazily discard the first N values.

However, the function must also change to accept a `stdx::generator<char>` in order to work with these results. To cover everything, your generator can take anything over which it can iterate, and take it by value:

```
template<typename Chars>
stdx::generator<char> lazy(Chars chars) {
    for (auto c : chars) {
        co_yield c;
    }
}
```

Of course this is more useful when the function actually does something to the elements in the sequence.

#### Optimization

However, this could potentially be inefficient if an expensive-to-move object is given (e.g., a large `std::array`). In this case, it would be nice to take the object by reference. We'll have to trust the caller that lvalues live as long as the iteration. But temporaries are a big no, so we can disable those:

```
template<typename Chars>
stdx::generator<char> lazy(const Chars& chars) {
    for (auto c : chars) {
        co_yield c;
    }
}

template<typename Chars>
stdx::generator<char> lazy(const Chars&&) = delete;
```

See [this CppCon video](https://youtu.be/dTeKf5Oek2c?t=2501) for an explanation on the deleted overload.

### Guarantee Parameter Lifetime

Now what about if iterators are important and you *must* have this iterator version? With a simple change, the range `lazy` will work as planned:

```
stdx::generator<char> lazy(std::string str) {
    for (auto c : lazy(str.begin(), str.end())) {
        co_yield c;
    }
}
```

By taking the parameter by value **and** using `co_yield`, the parameter being iterated over is sure to live for as long as the iteration. Success!

The same tweaks we made to the non-iterator solution apply to this as well. The parameter can be generalized and lvalues can be taken by reference if the caller is trusted with their lifetime.

However, there is a caveat. Generators come with some overhead. Returning from the function and then coming back and continuing from where it left off requires something akin to a state machine. By using `co_yield` here, we've turned this function into a generator as well, bringing in that extra overhead. Now the compiler might be smart enough to optimize this away. I can't say, and the compiler will surely get smarter about such things over time, but it is something to watch out for.

One way of getting around this is to make both versions do equal work without one relying on the other. This will require more code overall.

### Offload the Problem

Perhaps the simplest solution is to take a generator as a parameter. Since `lazy` becomes redundant at that point, let's implement `take` for `char`:

```
// Copying a generator is cheap! (Should just be a pointer)
stdx::generator<char> take(stdx::generator<char> chars, int n) {
    auto current = chars.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < n && current != chars.end(); ++i) {
        co_yield *current++;
    }
}
```

By doing this, we already accept anything produced by an earlier generator function and we let the caller figure out how they want to go from an actual container to a `stdx::generator`. One such method of doing so is this very `lazy` function as described above, taking containers by value and using `co_yield` on each element.

This method is probably the most popular. In C#, generator functions take `IEnumerable<T>`, not any container. Despite not starting with an `IEnumerable<T>`, its extension methods let users do `container.GeneratorFunction()`, making it seamless. In Java 8, generator functions take `Stream<T>` and containers offer a `.stream()` method as a bridge. This `lazy` function is equivalent to Java's `stream` method.